# I have SSRS auto report refreshing every minute. I takes long time to refresh and shows loading

Tags: reporting-services

I have SSRS line graph which is to be auto refreshed every minute. I takes a long time to refresh and shows loading icon until it is refreshed and the graph becomes blurred.

How to reduce the refreshing time and how to refresh the report in background and not to show the loading icon?

Comment: Annoying huh? Perhaps you could use a combination of data refresh options (Use cached data under _Manage Processing Options_) and add a frequent cache refresh plan (under _Manage Cache Refresh Plans_)

Answer (score 0):

**Reducing the report refresh time**

In most examples, the bulk of the time taken to refresh a report will be due to the dataset queries running. Therefore you should start by looking at those queries and investigating how they can be optimised to execute as fast as possible. As noted in the comments there are options to cache reports for performance, but given your requirement to refresh the report every minute I am assuming you will want the latest data, not a cached version.

**Refreshing the report "in the background"**

As far as I am aware, this is not possible.

Comment: There is an AutoRefresh setting at the Report level. This represents the number of seconds between automatic refreshes of the page. By default, it is set to 0.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem a [snapshot](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt707791.aspx) would be the way to go. You can set up Snapshots under the *Processing Options* tab when managing the report. With a snapshot, SSRS runs all the queries behind the scenes at a set interval or schedule. Then, when the user accesses a report, the only loading time is for the presentation layer.

That said, if a user tries to access a report while SSRS is running a snapshot, then the user will wait until the snapshot is finished, and thus the loading screen will appear. I would recommend you follow Nathan's advice and work on query optimization.

Comment: This is for SQL Server Reporting Services (2016 and later)

Comment: AndyZ, Snapshots were released in SSRS 2008, I believe, but were certainly in the 2008R2 release.